# Approaching meaning in this context

Tags: word-meaning

A U-turn is turning your vehicle around in the street to go back the way you came. To make a U-turn, signal and use the far left lane or the center left turn lane. You may make a legal U-turn:

> - Across a double yellow line when it is safe and legal.
> - In a residential district:
> - If there are no vehicles **approaching** you within 200 feet.
> - Whenever a traffic sign, light, or signal protects you from approaching vehicles.
> - At an intersection on a green light or green arrow, unless a "No Uturn" sign is posted.
> - On a divided highway, only if an opening is provided in the center divider.

Approaching from behind? Or approaching from front ? Over the crossroad for example.

Answer (score 2):

*Approaching* here is used quite simply in its most common sense:

> to move or become near or nearer to something or someone <sub>[www.m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approach)</sub>

Since no direction is specified in the example sentences, it does not matter what direction you are being approached from; behind, in front, or from a crossing road at a 58-degree angle clockwise and a 10-degree downslope.  If anybody is approaching you from anywhere, and they are less than 200 feet away, you must not make a U-turn.